# ENCENDER UN LED CON ARDUINO CON UN "1" Y APAGAR CON UN "0"

Tags: arduino

tengo problemas para encender un led con arduino, se tiene que encender el led cuando el usuario introduzca un "1" y mostrar una leyenda que diga "led encendido desde la computadora"  y se tiene que apagar cuando el usuario introduzca un "0" y mostrar una leyenda que diga "led apagado desde computadora", ademas debe de encender con bluethooth desde el móvil. 
¿Podrían ayudarme por favor?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial BT1(2,3);
int myLed= 12;
char s ='0';
int g = 0;

void setup() {
  Serial.println("LISTO :)");
  BT1.begin(9600);
  pinMode(myLed,OUTPUT);

}

void loop() {
   if(BT1.available()){
    Serial.println("SI ESTA LISTO");
    g=BT1.read();
    Serial.println(g);
    }
  if(g==49){
    digitalWrite(myLed,HIGH);
    Serial.println("led enciende desde celular");
    g=50;
  }
   if(g==48){
    digitalWrite(myLed,LOW);
    Serial.println("led apaga desde celular");
    g=47;
  }

  if(s=='1'){
    digitalWrite(myLed,HIGH);
    Serial.println("led enciende desde computadora");
  }

}
```

Comment: Podías porfavor agregar la info del dispositivo Bluetooth?
como sea hechale un ojo a este post: https://hetpro-store.com/TUTORIALES/bluetooth-hc-06-app-arduino/

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el problema sea que lees del Bluetooth en la variable g, pero tu if válida con s.

Cambia

```
If(s=='1')
```

Por

```
If(g=='1')
```

o sino, lo que te falta es añadir la lectura del sensor S en el bluetooth:

```
s=BT1.read();
```

Recuerda que en tu codigo tampoco tienes añadido el mensaje de la opcion 0:

```
  if(s=='0'){
    digitalWrite(myLed,HIGH);
    Serial.println("led apagado desde computadora");
  }
```